# no matching constructor for initialization of 'point'

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct, constructor

Sorry if I still ask about this, but the solution i've been given works if i do a small example, if i try to implement it in my project i keep getting the error in the title.
This is my struct

```
template<typename T>
struct element{
   int i;  
   int j;  
   T val;  

   element(){}
   element(T &other): val(other){} // this is the solution i previously got

   template<typename U>
   element(const element<U>& e): val(static_cast<T>(e.val)), i(e.i), j(e.j){}
   // this one is used to help the main class cast types.
};
```

In my sparseMatrix class i create a dynamic array of type element,

```
element<T> *m; // the class is also template
```

Everything works just fine with Fundamental data types.
What i need to do is to make my dynamic array, made of `elements`, work with custom data types.
The test i've been doing is with a struct point

```
struct point {
   int x; 
   int y; 

   point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
};
```

The constructor I implemented in the class is

```
explicit sparseMatrix(const T& d) : mat(0), capacity(0), n(0), def_value(d) {
    m = new element<T> [capacity];
}
```

When in the main i do

```
sparseMatrix<point> mcp(point(1, 2));
```

I get the error `no matching constructor for initialization of 'point'`
What am i doing wrong?
How can i solve this issue?
[note, i can't use c++11]

Comment: On an unrelated note, are you *sure* you want a pointer to `element<T>` and not a `std::vector`? With a vector you don't have to handle the reallocations yourself. Also, in the `sparseMatrix` constructor you show, you initialize `capacity` to zero and use it for the size of the data you allocate. Are you sure that's such a good idea?

Comment: I had to do this because for my project i'm not allowed to use stl containers. Every time an element is added to the matrix the capacity is increased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template-class `element` you store an instance of the type `T`. When an `element<T>` instance is created then `val` will be *default constructed*.

When you use `point` as `T` you will get an error because it doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @user7337963 Yes. The way you have designed your sparse matrix, it needs the contained types to have a default constructor.

Comment: do you mind to give me a small example? because this is something i've never come across

Comment: @user7337963 Your issue basically boils [down to this](http://ideone.com/Ax8Ark).  Solve that problem, and you basically understand the answer given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the solution i found for the "problem-solving-exercise" you gave me i came up with
foo **p = new foo *[10] correct me if i'm wrong.
trying to implement that my compiler suggested this: 
mat = *new val_type *[capacity];  
which to me looks awful but it's working. is it correct?

Comment: @user7337963 That `mat = *new val_type *[capacity]` will leak memory. Other than that allocating arrays of pointers might be one solution. Or just document the requirement of default construction.

Comment: @user7337963 -  I would suggest, as the other comment suggested, you document the preconditions to using your class.  This particular precondition is that the class requires a default constructor.

Comment: the reason i removed the default constructor from the class is because the default value has to be passed during construction phase. I'm trying to use you suggestions but i can't make it work.

Comment: Now i'm able to create point elements, when i try to add them to the sparseMatrix it gives me the error in the title.

Comment: I managed to make it work by doing this in the struct default constructor : element():val(val){} and again i know it's not ok but it works... so my problem is now : how can i properly initialize val in the default constructor in order to make it work with both fundamental and custom data types? i the beginning i did element():val(){} but that does not work with custom data types

Comment: forget all i said in the previous comments, it leaks a lot... Can you guys please post an example of code? i'm going crazy over this